# How to convert a calendar object to date in struts2 textfield tag

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am editing a users profile, I need a way to edit the user's date of birth. In my action class the dateOfBirth is a Calendar object. Now how can populate the date in the date of birth text field.

```
<s:textfield id="txtDob" name="dateOfBirth" />


public class Person {

    private Calendar dateOfBirth;
    public Calendar getDateOfBirth() {    
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Calendar dateOfBirth) {    
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

when i run the jsp, this is what i get inside the textfield

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=366229800000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=1981,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=33,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=222,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Comment: I haven't. I have been looking out for some solutions, yet to find any.

Comment: I have tried this dateOfBirth.time and got the date MM/dd/yy format how can i get it MM/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because struts2 has a set of type convertors out of the box and struts2 only supports date conversion and it uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request.

You can create your custom type convertor and can tell struts2 to use that type convertor for Calendar object.
creating a custom type convertor is quite easy and straight forward.make use of `StrutsTypeConverter` class being provided by S2 for this purpose

```
 public class MyConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
       .....
    }

    public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
       .....
    }
 }
```

- [TypeConversion-CreatingaTypeConverter](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CreatingaTypeConverter)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using s:textfield tag try using dojo ajax sx:datetimepicker tag. Before using dojo tags add respective jars.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example/title>
<s:head />
<sx:head />
</head>
<body>
<sx:datetimepicker name="dateOfBirth" label="Date Of Birth"
     displayFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i will never suggest some one a tag which is depricated

Comment: Actually I am using jquery datepicker, not the one in Struts-jquery plugin but actual jquery. is there any way to do with that or with the plugin.